# How do I use a dynamic variable in a react function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am developing a react app with a firebase backend. I loop through firestore collection and display the images from that collection.

> ```
> const getdata = Object.entries(mydata).map(pair => {
>     const key = pair[0]
>     const value = pair[1]
>     return (
>         <div className='image">
>         <img src={value} id={key} onclick={showpop} />
>         </div>
>     )
> }
> ```

When the image is clicked, it should show a pop up, and I am doing that like so:

> ```
> function showpop(){
>     var img = document.getElementById(//get value of the id here from the key);
>     img.onclick = function(){
>         //show popup here
>     }
> }
> ```

I have tried with `getElementById(key)`, `getElementById(props.key)`, but they all give me errors.

Comment: why  did you add another onclick function in showpop() ?

Comment: When I dont add the onclick, I get an error from this line : myImg.src = this.src;  saying src is not defined.

Comment: you can set the image src on showpop when you bind the `onclick={()=>{showpop(value)}}`, just like my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Reactjs, then this `onclick` event should be `onClick`

```
const getdata = Object.entries(mydata)
   .map(([key, value])=> (
      <div className='image">
        <img src={value} id={key} onClick={showpop} />
     </div>));
```

then:

```
function showpop(event){
   const {id} = event.target; //--> get the img id property
   const src =  event.target.getAttribute("src") //--> get the src attribute
   //--> show popup
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value when binding the function

```
<div className='image'>
   <img src={value} id={key} onclick={()=>{showpop(pair)}} />
</div>


function showpop(pair){
   console.log(pair)
}
```